# HttpWebRequest with Windows 8 Phone App

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8

When i try to make `HttpWebRequest` it is returning `System.Net.ProtocolViolationException` error.

```
private void txtGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest client =
            WebRequest.Create("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=jdbcn8yuwebwybxjpqzzxyhy");
        client.ContentType = "application/json";
        client.BeginGetResponse(ReadWebRequestCallBack, client);
    }

    private void ReadWebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult callBackResult)
    {
        var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest) callBackResult.AsyncState;
        if(myRequest != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callBackResult);
                txtContent.Text = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
            catch(WebException ex)
            {
                txtContent.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

When i remove this line `client.ContentType = "application/json";` there is a different error which is below

```
 {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult  asyncResult)
  at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
  at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at MyClimate.MainPage.ReadWebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult callBackResult)}
base: {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult as yncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.   <EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at MyClimate.MainPage.ReadWebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult callBackResult)}
   Response: {System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebResponse}
   Status: UnknownError
```

Comment: Well you shouldn't be specifying a content type when the *request* contains no content. Are you sure *that exact URL* is giving you the "not found" response otherwise?

Comment: after removing the `ContentType` only the `The remote server returned an error: NotFound.` error occured.

Comment: Hmm... works for me in a small console app...

Comment: Thanks, I am using Windows Phone 8 app. Will there be any problem in that?

Comment: I wouldn't have expected so, to be honest. I would possibly watch the traffic on the network - for example, using Wireshark and running the phone emulator. See if there's anything odd in the request or the response. Maybe you need to change the user agent, for example?

Comment: sorry i cant get you ? Can u give me an example ?

Comment: Download Wireshark. Install it. Run it. Monitor traffic. Write a small console app which manages to download that page, and examine the request and response. Then do the same in the phone emulator.

Comment: Thanks, I created console application and its working fine, but not windows phone 8

Comment: Yes, but that's the point of installing Wireshark. That way you can see the network traffic.

Comment: sorry i am not clear with your suggestion...

Comment: I'm not sure how I can put it any more clearly, I'm afraid.

Comment: hi actually i think the issue is related with network. For connecting to api it needs internet connectivity. But i when i tried accessing google in emulator internet explorer, its not getting connected. So is that the issue with internet connectivity. How to configure network in emulator for connecting to internet ?

Comment: I'm sure that's covered in tutorials all over the web - it's not suitable to ask in a *comment* on a different question here.

Comment: I just asked for basic startup. Ok thanks anyway.. let me google and if i found the answer i will post back here.

Comment: Check the response headers via the Visual Studio debugger. I am getting the same error you're getting, and the HTTP headers coming back have a X-Mashery-Error-Code header with a value of ERR_504_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error. Are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion. I am not with the testing environment right now. I will check it and let u know.

Comment: Can you post the code for the listener that you are calling to? Does the prefix of the listener match the beginning of the WebRequest? Also, if possible, put something in the listener that will log if it reaches the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues here. First of all remove `client.ContentType = "application/json";` because your method of request is GET and `ContnetType` is meaningless in GET. 
The second issue is the internet connection of your emulator check this setting of the Emulator virtual machine.

- In the Hyper-V Manager
- Click Emulator Virtual Machine settings
- Click on Windows Phone Emulator External Interface Select the Virtual
  switch which its name start by your physical network device name.

For more information see [Troubleshooting the Windows Phone 8 Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

[image]
The third issue is updating a UI control (TextBox) from another thread other than the UI thread.

Change

```
   txtContent.Text = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

to

```
   Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
      txtContent.Text = response.StatusCode.ToString();
   });
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the point `Click Emulator Virtual Machine settings` and the issue is because of network only

Answer (score 4):

You will get this `System.Net.ProtocolViolationException` because you do not have any **Post** and **get** method. Hope this will help you.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch)";
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        // Set the Method property to 'POST' to post data to the URI.
        request.Method = "POST";

        // start the asynchronous operation
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(CRequest), request);
```

Answer (score 0):

### **You can use like this it will work for your code**

just write  **client.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";**
and **client.Method = "POST";** in your txtGo_click button and use this method in your code

```
    private void ReadWebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult callBackResult)
    {
        var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callBackResult.AsyncState;
        if (myRequest != null)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callBackResult);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { txtContent.Text = response.StatusCode.ToString(); });
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { txtContent.Text = ex.Message; });
            }
        }
    }
```